# Determine Level Structure of Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am trying to output the level structure of a graph (for example, a graph with edges {{1,2},{2,3},{3,4},{3,5},{3,6},{4,7}} would have a level structure {1: {1}, 2: {2}, 3: {3}, 4: {4, 5, 6}, 5: {7}}).

Right now I am thinking of using BFS, keeping track of the level of the current and current's children at each loop. Since BreadthFirstScan is a built-in function I started there; I could not figure out which events might help to get the level.

Not re-implementing BFS would be ideal, but any suggestions are appreciated.

edit: Assuming no cycles and 1 root

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
GraphLevels[graph_, rootvertex_] :=
 Last@Reap[
  BreadthFirstScan[graph,
    rootvertex,
    {"DiscoverVertex" -> (Sow[#1, #3] &)}],
  _,
  Rule]

(* Default for no vertex provided: *)

GraphLevels[graph_] := 
 If[EmptyGraphQ[graph], {}, 
  GraphLevels[graph, First@VertexList[graph]]]

(* Test: *)

g = Graph[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}, {4, 7}}];

GraphLevels[g,1]

(* Out: {0 -> {1}, 1 -> {2}, 2 -> {3}, 3 -> {4, 5, 6}, 4 -> {7}} *)
```

You could also replace `Rule` with some other function to force it in line with your desired level specification, e.g. `(1 + #1) -> #2 &`. (The current version uses the distance, which has `1` at `0`.)

`Sow[#1, #3] &` sows each vertex discovered (which is supplied during `BreadthFirstSearch` as a first argument) with its distance from the `rootvertex` (which is supplied as a third argument) as a tag. The second argument to `Reap` (`_`) says to collect all sown tags, and the last argument to `Reap` is a function `f` to be applied to the tag and the sowed data, in that order (`f[tag, sowedlist]`). Here, it's `Rule`, so you get `tag -> sowedlist`. `Last@Reap[...]` then gets a list of all such applications, `{f[tag1, sowedlist1], f[tag2, sowedlist2], ...}`.

(You also could modify `Rule` to be any other function, if you want to store things differently, of course! But note that `Association` may be applied to the result of this `GraphLevels`, and then you could apply that association to a level value to extract that level quickly: `a = Association[GraphLevels[g, 1]]; a[4] (* Out: {4,5,6} *)`)

Note also that BFS can be faster than computing the distance for each vertex by a few(!) orders of magnitude for large graphs; check out `RepeatedTiming` with `g = RandomGraph[{2000, Binomial[2000,2]/2}]` ;) (Also note that solutions may not agree due to ambiguity in list ordering; this can be remedied by inserting or mapping a `Sort` at the appropriate point to normalize the solutions.)

Comment: Thank you! The explanation is really useful.

Comment: @JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ glad it helped! let me know if i could clear up any part of it :)

Answer (score 5):

BFS just gives you the distance from the starting vertex. So do that: compute the distance.

```
g = Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}, {4, 7}}]
root = 1;

GroupBy[
 Transpose@{VertexList[g], GraphDistance[g, root]},
 Last -> First
 ]

(* <|0 -> {1}, 1 -> {2}, 2 -> {3}, 3 -> {4, 5, 6}, 4 -> {7}|> *)
```